# Outline and border are shifted left and down

Tags: css, border

For some reason it seems that my outline and border is shifted down and left. I made a JSFiddle with the code so you can see whats wrong.

***( http://jsfiddle.net/FHB4j/ )***

This image right here is what it is supposed to look like. I made another element in my design the same, and its working. Although when using the same EXACT method here it doesn't work? It doesn't make since I must be making a stupid mistake.

**Huge Thanks in Advance!**

[image]

> *My CSS*

```
  .standard-content-module {
    width: 414px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  .standard-content-module header {
    width: 414px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #cc9900;
  }
  .standard-content-module p {}
  .standard-content-module-content_container {
    background: #cccccc;
    border: 5px #ffcc00 solid;
    outline: 10px #cccccc solid;
    width: 384px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 17px;
  }
  .standard-content-module-content_container p {}
```

> *My HTML*

```
<div class="standard-content-module">
    <header><p>Module Title</p></header>
    <div class="standard-content-module-content_container">
        <p>123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set .standard-content-module overflow visible (or just remove it)

```
.standard-content-module {
      width: 414px;
      overflow:visible;
  }
```

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/FHB4j/1/)